# relationship issues in laravel 8

Tags: eloquent, orm, laravel-8, relationship

I have three tables namely **category, subcategory**, and **services**.

```
Basically, I want a relationship on the above tables respectively,
1) category -> **has many** sub-category
2) individual subcategory -> **has many** services
```

or you can refer to the below screenshot to understand better
or click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/34sV7.png)

Category and sub-category table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->text('category_name')->nullable();
            $table->integer('parents_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

services table

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('services', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->text('ser_name')->nullable();
            $table->text('title')->nullable();
            $table->text('image')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->integer('cat')->nullable();
            $table->integer('sub_cat')->nullable();
            $table->integer('price')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('status')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

on delete, only particular services would be get updated or deleted and on either parent category or subcategory deletion, it gives error for services available under a particular subcategory to delete first

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your question correctly, i think you can use [foreign key](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) cascade on delete inside your migration file, this method will delete any children on that parent.

example

```
Schema::create('services', function (Blueprint $table) {
        // something
       $table->foreignId('sub_category_id')
                  ->onUpdate('cascade')
                  ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

i hope this will answer your question.

Comment: can you elaborate on this as I am new in laravel

Comment: laravel [migration](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations) can create table schema, in these schema you can use to blueprint your table, and in these migration you can insert also [foreign key](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) it will tell laravel that this table has relationship with other table. by setting up database relationship you might want to use [eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships), in these documentation it will explained how to use it, but basically whenever you call Category Model it will also return Subcategory and etc.